# How can i get the Bot Message ID and edit the Message - Discord JDA Java

Tags: java, discord, bots, discord-jda

For my school project i am learning how to set up a bot. I figured out how to get a message the Message ID. But the ID is not from the Bot, he get the ID from the Author who wrote the command. :

```java
if (content.equals("!dim")){
            channel.sendMessage("TEST!").queue();

            Message bot = event.getMessage();
            long messageID = bot.getIdLong();
            String s = String.valueOf(messageID);
            System.out.print(s);
            channel.editMessageById(messageID, "text").queue();
}
```

Error in Console:

```java
914706361378557982[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-19] ERROR RestAction - RestAction queue returned failure: [ErrorResponseException] 50005: Cannot edit a message authored by another user
net.dv8tion.jda.api.exceptions.ContextException
    at net.dv8tion.jda.api.exceptions.ContextException.here(ContextException.java:54)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.api.requests.Request.<init>(Request.java:71)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.RestActionImpl.queue(RestActionImpl.java:197)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.api.requests.RestAction.queue(RestAction.java:573)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.api.requests.RestAction.queue(RestAction.java:539)
    at MessageListener.onMessageReceived(MessageListener.java:68)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter.onEvent(ListenerAdapter.java:483)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.InterfacedEventManager.handle(InterfacedEventManager.java:96)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.hooks.EventManagerProxy.handleInternally(EventManagerProxy.java:88)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.hooks.EventManagerProxy.handle(EventManagerProxy.java:70)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.JDAImpl.handleEvent(JDAImpl.java:160)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.handle.MessageCreateHandler.handleInternally(MessageCreateHandler.java:123)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.handle.SocketHandler.handle(SocketHandler.java:36)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.onDispatch(WebSocketClient.java:952)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.onEvent(WebSocketClient.java:839)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.handleEvent(WebSocketClient.java:817)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.onBinaryMessage(WebSocketClient.java:991)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ListenerManager.callOnBinaryMessage(ListenerManager.java:385)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.callOnBinaryMessage(ReadingThread.java:276)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.handleBinaryFrame(ReadingThread.java:996)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.handleFrame(ReadingThread.java:755)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.main(ReadingThread.java:108)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.runMain(ReadingThread.java:64)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.WebSocketThread.run(WebSocketThread.java:45)
```

I can tell from the Error that my MessageId is not from the Bot. Is there anyway to get it from the MessageBot from the Bot.
If you need any more Information, i will update this post asap.

Comment: You tried it and it worked great? I have an idea. Read the docs for the Discord API.

Comment: No, i it didnt work. I edited this post, and updatet more information. I tried to do it myself first with the doc, and i couldnt get it. Im new to coding, and trying to improve my coding. Sorry for this misserable post that you had to read. @David Conrad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your issue is... the method you're calling will edit the message for the given `ID` (you can get that ID in any message event through `getMessageIdLong()`, and be careful not to mistake that with `getMessageId()`, since it returns a `String` and `editMessage()` requires a `long`). Alternatively, you can call `Message.editMessage(String newText).queue()` (directly from your `Message` object) to perform the editing. In order to retrieve the aforementioned object, use `getMessage()` from any `Message` event. If you still have any doubts regarding this matter, check out [the documentation](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/index.html).

Comment: I feel so dumb. I updated the post now. Yes i tried to put a String into a required Long. Thx you for being nice, and trying to help me!

Comment: Now! I understand the problem! The Messagelistener is not doing like i wanted. When the bot send a new message and i try to change it right after, i will get the message id by the human not the bot. Solution: if(event.getAuthor().isBot()) in right spot